# What does "?" means in ls -l output?

Tags: linux, filesystems, ls, systemd-run

I saw a few files/dir are inaccessible even to the root user:

`find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied`.

So I went a level deeper and ran `ls -l`; below is the output.

```
/run/user/125# ll
ls: cannot access 'gvfs': Permission denied
total 4
drwx------ 12 gdm  gdm  340 Sep  3 10:20 ./
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  80 Sep  3 10:19 ../
srw-rw-rw-  1 gdm  gdm    0 Sep  3 10:19 bus=
drwx------  3 gdm  gdm   60 Sep  3 10:19 dbus-1/
drwx------  2 gdm  gdm   60 Sep  3 10:19 dconf/
drwx--x--x  2 gdm  gdm   60 Sep  3 10:19 gdm/
prw-rw-r--  1 gdm  gdm    0 Sep  3 10:19 gnome-session-leader-fifo|
drwx------  3 gdm  gdm   60 Sep  3 10:19 gnome-shell/
drwx------  2 gdm  gdm  140 Sep  3 10:19 gnupg/
d?????????  ? ?    ?      ?            ? gvfs/
-rw-------  1 gdm  gdm  318 Sep  3 10:19 ICEauthority
d---------  3 gdm  gdm  160 Sep  3 10:19 inaccessible/
drwx------  2 gdm  gdm  100 Sep  3 10:19 keyring/
srw-rw-rw-  1 gdm  gdm    0 Sep  3 10:19 pk-debconf-socket=
drwx------  2 gdm  gdm   80 Sep  3 10:19 pulse/
srw-rw-rw-  1 gdm  gdm    0 Sep  3 10:19 snapd-session-agent.socket=
drwxr-xr-x  3 gdm  gdm  100 Sep  3 10:19 systemd/
```

Why do we see `?` against file/dir `gvfs`?

Comment: This is a nice addition to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103114/what-do-the-fields-in-ls-al-output-mean

Answer (score 13):

The question marks mean that `ls` can’t read the corresponding information; it reports that at the top of its output:

```
ls: cannot access 'gvfs': Permission denied
```

`gvfs` is inaccessible to all users except its owner, even to root, because it’s a user-owned FUSE mount — such mounts are inaccessible even to root, to prevent a malicious FUSE process from taking advantage of the situation:

```
$ mount|grep /run/user/125/gvfs
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/125/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=125,group_id=125)
```

The information displayed for a mount point comes from “inside” the mount, and the only user allowed to read the FUSE mount is the owner. (And yes, this is somewhat surprising given the expected privilege of the `root` user.)

Comment: :-) thx - `cat /etc/passwd | grep 125
whoopsie:x:120:125::/nonexistent:/bin/false
gdm:x:125:130:Gnome Display Manager:/var/lib/gdm3:/bin/false` , does `gdm` user have any default pass. I know, i should not be bothered. It's just to explore.

Comment: ?? bit amazed - well said- `And yes, this is somewhat surprising given the expected privilege of the root user.`

Comment: `gdm` doesn’t have a default password, no. The account is set up so that you can’t log in with it.

Comment: :-)  :-) hurray --> then --> `su gdm` --> no passwd promt --> but nothing happens, prompt still says root NOT gdm and ll returns same error.   :-) :-)  As you quoted - `The account is set up so that you can’t log in with it. `

Comment: User-owned FUSE mounts aren't readable by root by default because the FUSE process runs as the user and that process could detect the root user and provide malicious data to them.