# How to access /proc/ file (procfs) via SSHFS

Tags: proc, sshfs

Using a computer with Ubuntu 16.04 (no update suggestions please) I mounted `/proc/` at my Raspberry Pi 3B + (linux kernel version 4.19.88) via SSHFS:

```bsh
sshfs pi@192.168.0.4:/proc ~/procAtPi
ls -la ~/procAtPi
```

Here `ls` shows me all files in the Pi's `/proc` without any problems, just as I had connected directly via ssh. But when I try to read the files with `cat`, nothing is displayed here. The file content is only output to me when I connect directly via

```
user@remote:~$ ssh pi@192.168.0.4
pi@192.168.0.4:~$ cat /proc/stat
```

**How can I read out a file from procfs that I access via SSHFS?**

Some more observations I made:

- Using `sudo cat ~/procAtPi/stat` leads to `Access denied` (So root seems to have fewer access rights than the normal user?) but the files owner is root:

  ```
  user@remote:~$ ls -lai ~/procAtPi/stat
        16 -r--r--r--   1 root             root                0 Dez 24 00:00 stat
  ```
- The displayed owner differs depending on the access:

  ```
  user@remote:~$ ls -lai ~/procAtPi/
       ...
       171 dr-xr-xr-x   1 user             user                0 Jan 20 09:18 11045
       ...
  pi@192.168.0.4:~$ ls -lai /proc/
       ...
  2035700 dr-xr-xr-x   8 pi               pi                  0 Jan 20 09:18 11045
       ...
  ```
- Remote access to files in the Pi's sysfs (`/sys/`) seems to work fine.

A current workaround is to run a server on the Pi that reads the data from `/proc/stat` and makes it available via TCP. To do so, however, I have to start the server manually every time (I don't want an autostart because I don't need it all the time). I need access to `proc/stat` for a `htop`-like program that is supposed to monitor my Pi cluster.

Comment: Regarding the root access denied, [FUSE file systems are inaccessible to users other than their owners, including root](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/607691/86440).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `ls` shows me all files in the Pi's `/proc` without any problems, just as I had connected directly via `ssh`. But when I try to read the files with `cat`, nothing is displayed here.

As a workaround, use the `-o direct_io` option of `sshfs`:

```
# sshfs localhost:/proc /mnt/tmp
root@localhost's password:
# cat /mnt/tmp/self/stat
<nothing!>
# umount /mnt/tmp

# sshfs -o direct_io localhost:/proc /mnt/tmp
root@localhost's password:
# cat /mnt/tmp/self/stat
8242 (sftp-server) R 8236 8242 8242 0 -1 4194560 335 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 20 0 1 0 1846105 2506752 441 18446744073709551615 94732486082560 94732486157085 140730261312560 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 17 3 0 0 0 0 0 94732486190800 94732486194248 94732486483968 140730261319328 140730261319357 140730261319357 140730261319643 0
```

See [here](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/blob/d35470382b50aa10e4e81697b23183b50ee45941/include/fuse.h#L201) for a description of what that option is doing.

The problem with those files under `/proc` is that they appear as regular files of size = 0, yet they're not empty and contain data when read.

Notice that this problem is NOT caused by the SFTP protocol, and is not specific to `sshfs`.