# Unable to access nautilus mounted drive share for rsync copy.

Tags: ubuntu, nautilus

Over the last few days I've been attempting to run a rsync command against a CIFS drive share I can only mount via Nautilus. The standard 'mount -t cifs' command responds with a generic permissions 13 error but Nautilus works.

If I use Nautilus, you can see a new mount matching my user-id under /run/user/1004/gvfs. I can not access it.  I've reviewed few dozen searches on gvfs and FUSE, a review of GVFS and FUSE here [StackExchange description of gvfs shares](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77453/why-cannot-find-read-run-user-1000-gvfs-even-though-it-is-running-as-root) covers something close, but I can not seem to work it out to access the mount.

For the life of me, I can not seem to figure out how to gain access to it.  My desktop system is a Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Suggestions or pointers on what to do would be great.